# Any Jquery plugin to create a horizontal monthly calendar (one liner)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, calendar

I found many calendar plugins for jquery, however, I am searching for a plugin that displays a horizontal calendar with all days of the months in one line. Below the *date line* will be lines of additional data, days crossed or empty.

```
weekd: | M | T | W | T | F | ...
mdate: | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | ...
user1: | x |   |   | x | x | ...
user2: | x | x | x | x |   | ...
```

I thought I could use a table or chart plugin but did not find the right one. That's why I am asking for your experience. It would be great if the plugin takes the YYYY-mm-dd-dates and does the transformation to day number and weekday names automatically.

Optional: It would also be nice to zoom in and scroll left and right.

PS: The only one that I found and would give me a slight start is [Verbose Calendar](http://iamjpg.github.io/jQuery-Verbose-Calendar/).

Comment: I ended up writing my own plugin that you can see in action here: https://www.matheretter.de/ferien/

Comment: I need same thing and your calendar looks awesome, can you please provide me some info how i can achieve same thing, can you at least give some guidance how to approach to this solution, i asked question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42530379/custom-calendar-with-bootstrap-and-momentjs

Comment: @SuperMario'sYoshi Please see code release below. It's a custom script but you might take some ideas from it.

Answer (score 2):

I have finally found the time to get all files together and release them, as requested by so many people (sorry for the delay): https://github.com/q2apro/php-mysql-jquery-horizontal-calendar

[image: Horizontal Calendar PHP-Mysql-jquery]

[image: Screenshot 2]

This simple script should give you a starting point.

Comment: Nice job, vote up from me. 
Btw. i already finished this, i did it on javascript side and its working good.

Comment: Feel free to create a demo, best for others would be a fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

I have been looking for something similar for some time now.
The closest I have found (but paid) is this (see "Timeline" or "Free Busy View"):

[Smartphpcalendar](http://smartphpcalendar.com/features)

Also (paid too):

[Schudeler](http://dhtmlx.com/docs/products/dhtmlxScheduler/index.shtml)

However I'm still looking for a free solution. Let us know if you have made any progress.